# Which kind of test should I use for a library?

Tags: configuration, functional-testing, codeception

I'm developing a PHP library that I'd like to use in different projects. The library uses a REST-like service in the background. I don't want to write tests for the service API, but for the library.

Would I need to write unit tests? Or functional tests? Since it is a library I won't write acceptance test - I hope this is correct.

I don't know if this is important for the issue, but the library needs to login into the service API and uses an API-key for the next operations. Also, when the library gets tested, the operations before are important. It is a designer tool and I have operations like 'move rectangle', 'rotate rectangle' and so on and I would like to test several operations in a sequence that should bring a certain result.

I think that this is a kind of functional test. Or do I need both? Can unit tests work with a service in the background?

Comment: If test involves a service, it isn't a unit test.

Comment: @Naktibalda That's what I also thought. As a testing newbie I wasn't sure about this.